# What does Johnny's father write about?

Tags: song-of-the-south

In Disney's "Song of the South" 1946, Johnny's father leaves them for a time to go to Atlanta for newspaper work. Johnny has heard that everyone hates what his father writes for the paper.

Is the nature of his controversial writing known or guessable to us (or to a 1946 audience)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that that was a nod to Joel Chandler Harris, the compiler of the Uncle Remus Tales. Harris' day job was editor of the *Atlanta Journal-Constitution*, which he used as a platform to push for integration of freed slaves into society through education and voting rights. He was an avowed opponent of Jim Crow in a time and place when that was not a very popular view.